# Roblox Custom Screen UI not appearing

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

In Roblox Studio I am trying to replace the loading screen as they explain in this [documentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/ui/customizing-loading-screens). However, when I run the game all it does is show the default loading screen for its max 5 seconds and does not show the custom one I made, even while the game is still loading. I have tried tinkering with it and thoroughly read through the docs but can not figure out why the GUI will not load. The name of the GUI is "Loading Screen," and my localscript is attatched below. I would strongly appreciate anyone who could point out why the UI won't run.

```lua
local replicatedFirst = game:GetService("ReplicatedFirst")
local contentProvider = game:GetService("ContentProvider")
local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local players = game:GetService("Players")

local player = players.LocalPlayer
local playerGui = player.WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
local loadingScreen = script:WaitForChild("Loading Screen")

replicatedFirst:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen()

repeat task.wait() until game:IsLoaded()

local assets = game:GetDescendants()

local clonedLoadingScreen = loadingScreen:Clone()
clonedLoadingScreen.Parent = playerGui

tweenService:Create(clonedLoadingScreen.Background.GameTitle, TweenInfo.new(1, Enum.EasingStyle.Sine, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut, -1, true), {Position = UDim2.fromScale(clonedLoadingScreen.Background.GameTitle.Position.X.Scale, clonedLoadingScreen.Background.GameTitle.Position.Y.Scale + 0.02)}):Play()

for i = 1, #assets do
    local asset = assets[i]
    local percentage = math.round(i/ #assets * 100)
    
    contentProvider:PreloadAsync({asset})
    
    clonedLoadingScreen.Background.DisplayPercentage.Text = percentage.."%"
    clonedLoadingScreen.Background.DisplayAssetsLoaded.Text = "Loading Assest: "..i.."/"..#assets
    
    tweenService:Create(clonedLoadingScreen.Background.BarBackground.Bar, TweenInfo.new(0.2,Enum.EasingStyle.Sine, Enum.EasingDirection.Out), {Size = UDim2.fromScale(percentage/100, 1)}):Play()
    
    if i % 25 == 0 then
        task.wait()
    end
    
    if i == #assets then
        task.wait(1)
    end
end

for i, v in pairs(clonedLoadingScreen:GetDescendants()) do
    if v:IsA("Frame") then
        tweenService:Create(v, TweenInfo.new(0.5), {BackgroundTransparency = 1}):Play()
    elseif v:IsA("TextLabel") then
        tweenService:Create(v, TweenInfo.new(0.5), {TextTransparency = 1}):Play()
    end
end
```

Comment: If names of the aspects of the GUI are needed I can add that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your localscript is in ReplicatedFirst or not, if it isn't, move it there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).